# Flex : SpriteVisualElement can not add as a child Spark Label?

Tags: apache-flex

```
            var s : SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
                s.graphics.beginFill( 0xFFFF00 );
                s.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 100, 20 );
                s.graphics.endFill();
                s.width = 100;
                s.height = 20;
            this.addElement( s ) ;

            var l : Label = new Label();
                l.text = "text";
                l.width = s.width;
                l.height = s.height;
            s.addChild( l );
```

The follow code seems not to working ( Flex 4.5 ).

- What could cause this issue, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not being displayed because you're not adding Label (which is a UIComponent and works with the component lifecycle) to another UIComponent that will actually instantiate it properly.  Your SpriteVisualElement is not made to have UIComponents within it, it's made to have sprites which can draw itself.  Label is waiting for 'invalidateDisplayList' to be called so that it can draw itself.

Either do a force draw or use a UIComponent as the container for Label.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spark Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) is not a container; and therefore does not have an addElement method.  I assume you're getting a compile error because of this [but you didn't tell us what your problem was].

You can wrap the label up in a container, such as a [Group](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html) or [SkinnableContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html) and use your extra visual element as a child of the same group.

Or you could try the [addChild](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29) method of the Label.  It's odd to try to add Children to a component, such as Label, that is not intended as a container, though.

Comment: the code above work properly. none error at all. just the label is not displayed. and i dont add anything to Label instance. i am adding the label to the Sprite instance.

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev Perhaps you should re-write your question to include some of that information. If it confused me; it may confuse others.